# Mosh : client stay with "without contact" message

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, mac-osx

I'm trying to use mosh in replacement of ssh but it doesn't work on my computer.
On my Mac (Macos X LION), the client stay with this message and never connect :

```
mosh: Connecting... (10 s without contact.) [To quit: Ctrl-^ .]
```

I used homebrew to install mosh on my compute.
On my Server (ubuntu server), mosh-server seems to run without any problems. The UDP ports are open.

I try to figure out a solution but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling your firewall for a moment to make sure that it's not being blocked?  We've all been bitten by rule ordering mistakes.

Also, how large of a range do you have defined?  Here's the iptables rule I'm using:

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 60000:60999 -m comment --comment "100 allow mosh" -j ACCEPT
```